# vim comments autocomplete spuriously stops working

Tags: vim

`comments` remains the same in two `*.c` files:

```
set comments?
comments=sO:* -,mO:*  ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
```

However, in one file that has been open for a long time, the autocomplete in comments simply stops working. Any type of comment, `/*` or `//` does not auto-insert upon a newline. If I open a brand new `test.c` file, the auto-completion works as expected. Additionally, `set filetype?` produces the same result, `cpp`, for both files.  This has happened to me consistently when I have files open for long periods of time, such as in tmux sessions, and I've found it difficult to reliably reproduce on-demand.

What reasons could this stop working after a long time? The only fix is to exit all my buffers and re-open them.

Answer (score 1):

This was not a problem in the `comments` variable, but in `formatoptions`.

My continual tweaking of vim settings must screw with it after a long time.

I realized this after finding this resource: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/how-can-i-get-vim-to-stop-putting-comments-in-front-of-new-lines